# How can I convert a varchar field of the form: YYYYMMDD to a datetime in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, datetime

How can I convert a varchar field of the form YYYYMMDD to a datetime in T-SQL?

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
select convert(datetime, '20081030')
```

Comment: I had to specify a format as well.

 SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '20081030', 102)

Comment: Maybe that is dependent on your default settings... I guess it's better to specify a format no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CONVERT() function?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx